# Understanding vagrant with a docker provisioner

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

So my goal here is to have Vagrant spin me up a VM that I can use as a rails web application development environment.  I am very, very new to Vagrant, Docker, etc. and wanted to check if this even makes sense:

Should I be creating one Docker image, or two?  My thought was that one image would be for rvm, ruby, and rails, and the other image would be for Apache.

The goal would be something that could be distributed to a few people, who would then get the exact same environment set up easily.

Here is my current Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    config.vm.box = "phusion/ubuntu-12.04-amd64"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", :guest => 80, :host => 5000

    # Share the docker configs
    config.vm.synced_folder "./docker", "/docker"

    config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
        d.build_image "-t me/rvm-dev /docker/rvm-dev"
        d.run "me/rvm-dev"

    end
    config.vm.host_name = "coursera-rail.dev"
    config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest:80, host:8080  
end
```

And here is my current (probably wrong) Dockerfile
(as an aside, I am trying to find some good guidance on creating a "docker" user account so I don't run everything as root)

```
## Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/downloads

## Install RVM, Ruby, Rails
RUN cd /tmp/downloads
RUN \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby --rails
```

Lastly, the above works, and if I use vagrant ssh I can head in to my VM, but obviously I am unable to use RVM without doing docker run -i -t me/rvm-dev and getting a shell with docker.  Is this supposed to be the workflow?

Comment: Not to wise about a workflow myself, but maybe https://blog.abevoelker.com/rails-development-using-docker-and-vagrant/ works

Comment: Following the best practices of Docker you should not run this command: `RUN apt-get upgrade -y` it can break previous images. https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#the-dockerfile-instructions

Comment: Can you try if `docker exec -it <docker-container-id> /bin/bash` fits your needs? If not, can you describe what you want to achieve in more detail? What should be the result?

Answer (score -1):

In my humble opinion, the best flow would be to

1)  separate your app and db stack into vagrant boxes

or

2)  run docker on the host (the physical machine) and your DB instance (mysql, etc..) inside a vagrant box.

Option one is best because you are "sandboxing" both layers of the stack (DB and APP) inside Vagrant thus leaving the OS on your local machine (windows, Linux, Mac OSX) instact. Of course, you could install/run your IDE on the physical machine.